# Best practice for Excel data extraction

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

If I have .xlsx file created by Excel 2019, what will be the best practice
to extract data and turn into JSON format using the latest Data Hub Framework?

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting data into MarkLogic, you generally need its format to be either JSON, XML, CSV, text, or binary. So for your use case, you'd want to use a tool to convert that .xlsx file into one of the above formats first. There are dozens of such tools out there - pick one that works for your preferred programming language.